# How to mix AND OR operators in find conditions CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to write this query in CakePHP:

```
SELECT * FROM pm_management.chk_master_xs_tasks  
    where (eq_model = 'D11 R' OR eq_model = 'TODOS') AND (pm_type = 'XD' OR pm_type = 'XS');
```

I have tried severals ways like this:

```
$this->ChkMasterXsTask->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array('AND' => array(
               array('OR' => array('ChkMasterXsTask.eq_model' => $eq_model,
                                   'ChkMasterXsTask.eq_model' => 'TODOS')),
               array('OR' => array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => $pm_type,
                                   'ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => 'XS'))
                )
            ),     
        ));
```

But the result is not the expected. Also I saw related questions but doesn't work for me.

Thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem arises from this code *(and this problem is repeated for eq_model)*

```
array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => $pm_type,
      'ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => 'XS')
```

which tries to assign 2 values to the same key of that associative array.  You could rewrite your code to this:

```
array(array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => $pm_type),
      array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => 'XS'))
```

---

Another option which improves readability, uses SQL's `IN` function. The equivalent SQL becomes

```
SELECT * 
FROM pm_management.chk_master_xs_tasks  
WHERE eq_model IN ('D11 R', 'TODOS') 
  AND pm_type IN ('XD', 'XS');
```

Which should make your `find` a little easier write:

```
$this->ChkMasterXsTask->find('all', array(
        'conditions' => array(
          'ChkMasterXsTask.eq_model' => array($eq_model, 'TODOS'),
          'ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => array($pm_type, 'XS'))
        ));
```

Comment: Thanks for take the time to response my question. I use the same key because I need two possible values for it, note that I use an OR operator to retrieve information if `ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type` is equals to `$pm_type` or `'XS'`. On the other hand I will try the option you gave me to test.

Comment: The option with `IN` function solved my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

just I see a error y your code, there is a comma, that shouldn't be there.

```
  $this->ChkMasterXsTask->find(
        'all', array(
          'conditions' => array(
            'AND' => 
               array('OR' => array(
                 array('ChkMasterXsTask.eq_model' => $eq_model),
                 array('ChkMasterXsTask.eq_model' => 'TODOS')
                 ),

                 array('OR' => 
                   array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => $pm_type),
                   array('ChkMasterXsTask.pm_type' => 'XS')
                 )
            ))     
          ));
```

Comment: Thanks for response my question. I deleted the comma but the result was the same. I don't think that is the problem.